# Call python script as module with input from bash script

Tags: python, bash

From a bash function, I want to call a python script which prompts for input, and I need to run that script as a module using `python -m`

Here is select_pod.py

```py
# above this will be a print out of pods
pod = input('Pick pod')
print(pod)
```

Here is the bash function:

```sh
function foo() {
  POD=$(python3 -m select_pod)
  kubectl exec $POD --stdin --tty bash
}
```

I can't get the input to work, i.e. "Pick pod" is not printed to the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `POD=$(python3 -m select_pod)`, the `POD=$(...)` means that any output printed *to stdout* within the parentheses will be captured within the `POD` variable *instead* of getting printed to the screen. Simply `echo`ing out `POD` is no good, as this will first be done once the Python script has finished.

What you need to do is to duplicate the output of the Python program. Assuming Linux/Posix, this can be done using e.g.

```sh
POD=$(python3 -m select_pod | tee /dev/stderr)
```

Because your terminal shows both [stdout and stderr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams), [duplicating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)) the output from stdout to stderr makes the text show up.

Hijacking the error channel for this might not be ideal, e.g. if you want to later sort the error messages using something like `2> ...`. A different solution is to just duplicate it directly to the [tty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tty_(Unix)):

```sh
POD=$(python3 -m select_pod | tee /dev/tty)
```

Comment: Yeah that worked, thanks. $POD will indeed contain the full stdout but I can split that and grab the last piece.

Answer (score 1):

You can change `sys.stdout` before `input` :

```
import sys
save_sys_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = sys.stderr
pod = input('Pick pod')
sys.stdout = save_sys_stdout
print(pod)
```

So that `POD=$(python3 -m select_pod)` will work and you don't need to do split after.

Comment: I thought about going down that road, but that's unfortunately not an option for my use case as I won't be in control of the python.